# Incorporating several Python script tools into one tool and have user input determine section of script run?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-script-tool

I have a series of script tools created and work well in ArcMap 10.2.2 just fine.  These tools generate a series of buffer features from an input feature class.  I have these as separate tools each tool with a different set of buffer distances.

I want to be able to make one tool where the input feature class is chosen, then the set of buffer distances chosen out of a list from the script tool UI.

Example below of what is needed

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Buffers.gdb"
InPut = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

#"select buffer situation B or A (not optional must be A or B)"


# Situation A Buffer 1
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(InPut,"first_Buff","16 METERS","FULL","ROUND","ALL")
# Situation A Buffer 2 
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("first_Buff","second_Buff","5 METERS","FULL","ROUND","ALL")

# Situation B Buffer 1
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(InPut,"first_Buff","20 METERS","FULL","ROUND","ALL")
# Situation B Buffer 2 
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("first_Buff","second_Buff","10 METERS","FULL","ROUND","ALL")
```

Comment: I think that what you wish to achieve, can be done by "Multiple Ring Buffer" script tool in  Analysis toolbox. It is a script so in case you need to do something little different it could be a good source for inspiration/modification...

Answer (score 5):

Something like this might work

```
import arcpy 
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Buffers.gdb" 
InPut = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Situation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

if Situation == 'Situation A':
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(InPut,"first_Buff","16 METERS","FULL","ROUND","ALL")
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis("first_Buff","second_Buff","5 METERS","FULL","ROUND","ALL")

if Situation == 'Situation B':
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(InPut,"first_Buff","20 METERS","FULL","ROUND","ALL")
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis("first_Buff","second_Buff","10 METERS","FULL","ROUND","ALL")
```

You'd then create a tool in ArcToolbox with a second parameter for Situation - set this as Text and create a [Filter](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/creating-tools/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm#GUID-3CB5FAF4-43DD-4C84-8AFE-08039A72B3E0) to create a drop-down list of 'Situation A' and 'Situation B'.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this:

1. Use a second parameter to enable a pick list of buffer distances to be presented.  This means using arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) in your script *as well as* configuring the value list using the Parameters tab of the tool's Properties.
2. Using the variable value (set in 1.) within an if/else construct to specify which lines of code are run.